# Are there criteria that allows you determine if something is out of the scope of ethics?

Tags: ethics, metaphysics

Are there criteria that all you determine if something is out of the scope of ethics? Some people said that it is immoral to believe in God, but how can you argue against that if you cannot determine it to be out of the scope of ethics? How can you justify it being out of scope? What are then the criteria to determine if a statement is out of the scope of ethics and therefore irrelevant to ethics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethics (the science of the ideal human character) covers a vastly wide range of questions some of which are in the scope of meta-ethics and others may belong to specialized applied ethics according to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics#Meta-ethics):

> Meta-ethics is the branch of philosophical ethics that asks how we *understand*, *know* about, and what we *mean* when we talk about *what is right and what is wrong*. An ethical question pertaining to a particular practical situation—such as, "Should I eat this particular piece of chocolate cake?"—cannot be a meta-ethical question (rather, this is an applied ethical question). A meta-ethical question is abstract and relates to a wide range of more specific practical questions. For example, "Is it ever possible to have a secure knowledge of what is right and wrong?" is a meta-ethical question... Aristotle implies that less precise knowledge is possible in ethics than in other spheres of inquiry, and he regards ethical knowledge as depending upon habit and acculturation in a way that makes it distinctive from other kinds of knowledge.

> Studies of how we know in ethics divide into cognitivism and non-cognitivism; these, respectively, take descriptive and non-descriptive approaches to moral goodness or value. Non-cognitivism is the view that when we judge something as morally right or wrong, this is neither true nor false. We may, for example, be only expressing our emotional feelings about these things. Cognitivism can then be seen as the claim that when we talk about right and wrong, we are talking about matters of fact. The ontology of ethics is about value-bearing things or properties, that is, the kind of things or stuff referred to by ethical propositions. Non-descriptivists and non-cognitivists believe that ethics does not need a specific ontology since ethical propositions do not refer. This is known as an anti-realist position. Realists, on the other hand, must explain what kind of entities, properties or states are relevant for ethics, how they have value, and why they guide and motivate our actions.

If you adopt the Non-cognitivism POV regrading your example question assuming this is really a meta-ethics question, then you don't need to argue against it since it is not a propositional argument at all, thus you don't even have any propositional attitude, you only express your certain free-floating emotional feelings about your certain (religious) belief which you're unconditionally entitled. If you take the opposite view, then it's much harder to argue since you'll need to specify its ontic bearing value which seems complicated in your case due to its innate non-practical feature.

Your example question could also be out of ethics scope due to its obvious abstractness and not action based without any material consequence directly at least, and if you think this has nothing to do with your ideal character building...

Answer (score 0):

Ethics is a domain that takes place in a given 'mood' or 'modality' -- the deotological or moral modality of permission and obligation -- 'should-ness'.  It has to deal with statements that can be violated, and for which there is a potential corrective mechanism that attempts to limit violations.

There are at least three other modalities that are clearly not part of ethics.  The modality of possibilities and necessities, the modality of hypothetical mental constructions, and the modality of pure wishes.  The statements of the first of these cannot be violated.  The statements of the second can be upheld or violated, but the value of their disposition is neutral -- there is no intention to achieve a given state, so they do not precipitate attempts at correction.  The statements of the last do have a preferred state, but they do not apply to anyone but the person wishing, so any correction would be internal.

These modalities can be combined, and they influence one another.  For instance, wishes can become moral contents if you adopt a morality that is hedonistice or utilitarian in nature.  This creates an overlapping modality of second-person wishes, which then has moral character, because making ourselves or one another happy becomes a duty we can shirk.  Likewise, one can have a consequentialist component to morality which imports some necessities and possibilities.  If we are obligated to forestall man-made natural disasters or if we are obligated to keep our children safe, for instance, this creates a mixed modality that requires us to make predictions of possibilities with moral character.  Again, this is ethics, because we can fail at it, and we want everyone not to.

But anything belonging purely to non-moral modalities or combinations those have with one another is outside ethics.

Your question about God depends upon the observed facts of your culture's logic and psychology.  If you take up the Scholastic position that it is logically impossible not to believe in God (without just lying about it) then belief or disbelief is not part of ethics (although the lying would be).  It is in the modality of necessity.

If your belief in God is entirely Deist, and has no effect on your actions, but is just a way of conveniently framing things, it is equally not moral.  It is just something in the modality of mental constructions.

If your ethics is consequentialist, and belief in God causes you to just pray rather than acting, that is immoral.  A consequentialist morality prefers for you to do what you can to guide outcomes in a proper direction.  But you have to have ethically decided upon that obligation already.